# How does linux find an exe without the full search path

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, executable

What is linux doing in the background to locate an executable file when I don't give it the entire search path. Or more can someone describe the process of it finding the executable.

Comment: "Linux" meaning what, exactly? The `execlp` standard C library call (as used when something that's not the shell tries to execute an external command)? The shell? Something else?

Comment: ...I mean, if you were asking about the Linux kernel itself, it *doesn't* allow executables to be called without a fully qualified path; its `execve` syscall has no search functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the PATH environment variable. See  : http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: What "it"? If the question is about the shell, then this answer is incomplete -- there's also evaluation of aliases, builtins, functions; the hash lookup for cached PATH locations; etc. If it's about the `execl*` family of C library calls, then yes, this is correct. Since the OP is asking only about "Linux", it's hard to determine the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this:

```
which(){
    local program="$1" 
  case "$program" in
    /*) #If it's an absolute path, we're done
        echo "$program"; return 0;;
    */*) #If it has a slash but it's not an absolute path, absolutize
        echo "$PWD/$program"; return 0;;
      *) 
        #Otherwise split $PATH on ':'
        (
        IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do
        #And search for a so-named executable in each component
          ! test -x "$dir/$program" || { echo "$dir/$program"; exit 0; }
        done
        ) 
      ;;
  esac
  return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution), "Command search and execution":

> After a command has been split into words, if it results in a simple command and an optional list of arguments, the following actions are taken.
>
> 1. If the command name contains no slashes, the shell attempts to locate it. If there exists a shell function by that name, that function is invoked as described in [Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions).
> 2. If the name does not match a function, the shell searches for it in the list of shell builtins. If a match is found, that builtin is invoked.
> 3. If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, Bash searches each element of `$PATH` for a directory containing an executable file by that name. Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files to avoid multiple `PATH` searches (see the description of `hash` in [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)). A full search of the directories in `$PATH` is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table. If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named `command_not_found_handle`. If that function exists, it is invoked with the original command and the original command's arguments as its arguments, and the function's exit status becomes the exit status of the shell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error message and returns an exit status of 127.
> 4. If the search is successful, or if the command name contains one or more slashes, the shell executes the named program in a separate execution environment. Argument 0 is set to the name given, and the remaining arguments to the command are set to the arguments supplied, if any.
> 5. If this execution fails because the file is not in executable format, and the file is not a directory, it is assumed to be a *shell script* and the shell executes it as described in [Shell Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Scripts).
> 6. If the command was not begun asynchronously, the shell waits for the command to complete and collects its exit status.